# How to call specific Controller method via DropDownList from SpecificView.aspx on Form in MVC.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to call specific method ( probably action event ) of DropDownList when some item has been selected. When this will occure, I have to fetch the data from 2 tables. For that, I would require some action to register, This Is almost done, but with empty arguement, I need that when user clicks on List or select some data from it, it should post back the controller method which will be called via arguments of object( tblCourse, int id) like...

Now In the View.aspx , Code is:

```
   <%: Html.DropDownList("ProgramName", ViewData["ProgramID"] as SelectList,new { onchange = @"
        var form = document.forms[0]; 
        form.action='OnProgramSelection';
        form.submit();"
    }) %>
```

and in Controller:

```
    public bool OnProgramSelection(tblProgram a_Programs)
    {
        /*
        string ProgramName = a_tblProgram.ProgramName;
        string instituteName = a_tblProgram.tblInstitute.InstituteName;
        */
        return false;
    }
```

I want something, that OnProgramSelection can accept any no of arguments of whatever the type would be.

Answer (score 0):

To define a method that takes a variable number of parameters use the `params` keyword

> The params keyword lets you specify a method parameter that takes a
>   variable number of arguments.
>
> You can send a comma-separated list of arguments of the type specified
>   in the parameter declaration, or an array of arguments of the
>   specified type. You also can send no arguments.
>
> No additional parameters are permitted after the params keyword in a
>   method declaration, and only one params keyword is permitted in a
>   method declaration.

[From MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)